# python - accessing superclass attributes

Tags: python, inheritance

Hi I want to achieve the following in python, however I cant figure out what to replace the line `super.a = b` with:

```
class Super:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1

class Sub(Super):
  def method(self, b):
    super.a = b
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An `Sub` *is a* `Super`, i.e. all instances of `Sub` can be treated exactly like instances of `Super`. In your case, that means you simply set `self.a = b`.